# This doesn’t seem [professional] …

Tags: discussion, tagging

As an outsider, I wanted to gauge whether career questions are on-topic here (due to an off-topic question asked on a site I moderate). Turns out [they aren’t](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/a/150/39335). However, before I found that, I stumbled across the [professional](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professional) tag, which seems to be a [Meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and not applied consistently.

You may want to consider getting rid of it.

Related: [What tags relate specifically to professional restaurant issues?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1869/39335)

Comment: Professional is not limited to career.  For example a professional kitchen.

Comment: @paparazzo: Sure, but it does not seem to be applied consistently either and also goes against the [linked meta discussion](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1869/39335).

Comment: Just wanted to chime in with a shout out to reddit.com/r/chefit for industry and career discussion. @Wrzlprmft

Answer (score 2):

The consistent theme that I see in all of these questions is that most seem to be asking what professionals do in commercial kitchen settings. I can see the argument for how this falls under the category of ["dependent tags"](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/434/please-zap-the-meta-tags-and-dependent-tags), but to a degree I think it's useful for questions about specific commercial practices. Our site is about cooking in general, and specific terminology or processes in certain contexts are both within our scope *and* a specialized area of knowledge that someone could use a tag to helpfully locate.

The related tag https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restaurant has a couple good questions in line with what I mean here. For example, we've got a couple language-related questions for [menu terminology](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/75352/what-does-it-mean-for-a-menu-to-be-a-set-menu) and [equipment](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/71020/is-there-a-specific-name-for-the-mise-en-place-containers-used-in-professional-k) found or identified in commercial restaurant operations, and here's one about a [specific griddle-based technique](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/47212/what-is-the-liquid-often-ladled-onto-the-grill-top-in-restaurants) observed in a restaurant setting (which presumably the OP might want to replicate at home). Here's one very specifically about [walk-in organization](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13820/how-to-organize-a-walk-in-fridge-for-a-mid-size-kitchen) - something that applies almost exclusively to commercial kitchen operations.

So - there appear to be some useful and valid uses of the tag(s). There are also questions tagged that are off-topic for the site and closed as such, including questions about career advice.

However, neither "restaurant" nor "professional" are terribly descriptive, so instead I propose that we create a brand new tag: "professional-practices" or something similar. (I propose that we avoid using "restaurant-practices" so that it can more broadly apply to bakeries and other commercial operations.) This tag should include a good meta description noting that it's intended for questions about practices in commercial cooking environments - but also *not* for specific off-topic things like career advice.

We can then re-tag "good" questions under the existing tags to this new one, remove the older tags to depreciate them, and/or set the old tags up as synonyms to the new one to help guide users when tagging new questions.